# How to configure custom filter for git grep?

Tags: git, mozilla-sops

I am using [mozilla/sops](https://github.com/mozilla/sops) for encrypting and storing the secrets on git. They suggested [a git diff filter](https://github.com/mozilla/sops#47showing-diffs-in-cleartext-in-git) to decrypt the data on `git diff` and it shows the actual diff of secret instead of diff of cipher-text.

I configured this git filter using following commands.

```
git config diff.sopsdiffer.textconv "sops --decrypt --config /dev/null"
```

and adjusted `.gitattributes` with `*?.sops.yaml diff=sopsdiffer` attributes.

This basically means for `abc.sops.yaml` file git diff will decrypt the file content and shows dif f of original secret.

Similarly, I want to use `git grep` to decrypt and search in the decrypted content. However it does not work.

I used following commands to configure git grep filter.

```
git config grep.sopsgrepper.textconv "sops --decrypt --config /dev/null | grep -"
```

and adjusted `.gitattributes` with `*?.sops.yaml grep=sopsgrepper` attributes.

I then tested it with `git grep "secret_value"`.

Any help/hint would be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: There is a `diff=` in `.gitattributes` but there's no `grep=`. (You can set arbitrary junk to arbitrary values: if Git isn't using `nonsense`, the `nonsense=nothing` setting is just ignored.) That aside, `*?.sops.yaml` is an odd pattern: it means "any number of characters, followed by at least one of any character, followed by .sops.yaml" so it means you won't match `.sops.yaml`, but usually nobody cares whether you match the empty string here. It's not wrong, it's just odd.

Comment: This pattern is intentional to avoid `.sops.yaml` file.

Comment: Okay, I further probe into git-scm doc and realized there is is not `grep` filter driver for git. That means I cannot use the driver feature for `git grep ...`

Comment: That's what I said, there's no `grep=` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I further probed into git-scm doc and realized there is is not `grep` filter driver for git. That means I cannot use the driver filter for `git grep ...`